# Error : This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

This might be a very easy to spot mistake but I am not the most familiar with the Django queries so I have been breaking my head for hours trying to solve that.

I have a Django Rest app and there I have 2 models:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, default="UNK", choices=STATUS_TYPES)
    started_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)


class StudentStatusHistory(BaseTimestampModel):
    """Table of status changes for Students"""
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        "core.Student", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="StatusHistory"
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, blank=True, default="UNK", choices=STATUS_TYPES
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

For reference:

```py
STATUS_TYPES = [("UNK", "Unknown"), (“PASS", “Passed"), (“FAIL", “Failed")]
```

I am trying to write a query that calculates for how many students their status changed to `Pass` within the time window of a week or less.

So for example if a `Student.started_date` is `2023-07-15 12:22:22` and the `StudentStatusHistory.created_on` field is `2023-07-21 12:22:22`, for a student with `Student.status` that equals `PASS`, I want to count this student because they passed in less than a week (in 6 days in this example).

Additionaly, I want to calculate this count only for students that started the current month.

What I have so far is:

```py
current_month_start = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, 1)

# Subquery to filter StudentStatusHistory objects for each Student object within a week or less
pass_within_week_subquery = StudentStatusHistory.objects.filter(
            student_id=OuterRef(“pk"),
            status="PASS",
            created_on__range=(OuterRef("started_date"), OuterRef(“started_date") + timedelta(weeks=1))
        )

# Subquery to filter Student objects created within the current month
student_within_month_subquery = Student.objects.filter(
            started_date__gte=current_month_start,
            pk=OuterRef(“pk"),
        )

# Main queryset to annotate Student objects with pass_within_week count
student_objects_with_pass_within_week = Student.objects.annotate(
            pass_within_week_count=Subquery(
                pass_within_week_subquery.annotate(count_pass_within_week=Count("pk")).values(“count_pass_within_week"),
                output_field=IntegerField()),
            is_within_month=Exists(student_within_month_subquery),
        )

# Count the number of student objects that satisfy the condition
count_student_pass_within_week = student_objects_with_pass_within_week.filter(pass_within_week_count__gt=0,
is_within_month=True).count()

return Response(data= count_student_pass_within_week)
```

(I am not sure what’s up with the python format, but please ignore or edit that part)

Everything is running seemingly smoothly until the last line about the count that returns the error:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

I read a lot about the OuterRef, Subqueries, etc and I thought that by using them in a main queryset would solve this problem but clearly not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this simpler with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.db.models import F

Student.objects.filter(
    StatusHistory__status='PASS',
    StatusHistory__created_on__range=(
        F('started_date'),
        F('started_date') + timedelta(weeks=1),
    ),
).distinct().count()
```

we thus filter on the `Student`s to only retain the ones with a related `StatusHistory` that has `status='PASS'`, and the `created_on` in the time range of `started_date` and `started_date` and a week. We then count the *distinct* `Student`s that match this. We need to use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent counting the student multiple times, if the status is set to `PASS` multiple times within that week.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the manager to fetch the related objects in reverse. Therefore
> normally the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` is *plural*,
> for example `status_changes` instead of <s>`StatusHistory`</s>.

Comment: That is indeed a way simpler approach! 
It seems to be doing the job, thank you!